# How do I make the shell program exit when the user enters an input that is not y or Y?

Tags: shell, sh

I want to make the program exit out of the loop when the user types in a value that is not y or Y

```
#! /bin/sh
#initialise variable continue as "y"
continue="y"
while [ $continue = "y" -o "Y" ] # condition to continue the repetition
do
    echo "Please enter a station name to start search"
    read name

    result=`grep -w "^$name" STATIONS.TXT`
    if [ -z "$result" ]; then # the input station is not in the file
        echo "$name was not found in the file"
    else # the input station is in the file
        echo "$name was found in STATIONS.TXT"
    fi
    echo "Do you want to have another go? (enter y or Y to confirm, other to quit)"
    read input
    continue=$input
done
echo "End of the search program."
```

Comment: `[ $continue = "y" -o "Y" ]` doesn’t do what you think it does. It tests whether `$continue = "y"` _or_ `"Y"` is true, and the latter always is.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is your friend.

Comment: Try to get into a habit of always put variables in quotation marks, especially if they come from a user. Otherwise any white space can wreak havoc in you code. Type `"$continue"` instead of `$continue`. When there are no variables, single quotation marks are better because you don't have to worry about any special characters.

Comment: Regarding using user input in a grep regular expression: characters like `.*^$[]` are not literal in regex. You can use `grep -F` (fixed string), but then you can't use `^`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is quite close to how it should look, except that operator `-o` doesn't works on values but on entire expressions.

The correct notation would be:

```
while [ "$continue" = 'y' -o "$continue" = 'Y' ]
```

... or a variant that is a little better defined in the standard (it works on a greater variety of shell implementations):

```
while [ "$continue" = 'y' ] || [ "$continue" = 'Y' ]
```

... or a little more universal way based on a regular expression which will allow matching "yes" and "Yes":

```
while printf '%s' "$continue" | grep -q -x '[Yy]\(es\)\?'
```

(Notice that I've changed the style of quotation marks to a safer one.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `while :; do` for the while loop (or `while true; do` - they both return zero).

Then immediately after `read input`, use this to break the loop:

```
case $input in [Yy]);; *) break;; esac
```

This breaks the loop, and finishes the program, for anything other than a single `y` or `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

To test for either *Y* or *y*, you can use

```
while [[ $continue == [yY] ]]
```

Basically, you can have any glob-pattern on the right-hand side of a `[[ ... == ... ]]` command.

Note: This answer would work in bash (or zsh, or ksh). I provided it, because initially, the question was tagged as *bash*. Now it turned into a POSIX-shell question, and my answer is then of course not valid anymore.

Comment: This only works in shells that support such pattern matching. The question does not mention a specific shell, so we have to assume only POSIX-compliant features are available.

Comment: At the time I wrote the answer, the question was tagged bash. Therefore I suggested a bash answer.